# Creat a Hash within a loop in Rails Between two associate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has two models Student and  Parent where `student` 
`belongs_to` `parent`.

Parent has attributes `name` and `contact_no`

What I want to do is to based on some condition

```
@h=Hash.new
@students = Student.find(:condition)
@students.each do |student| 
  @h[@student.parent.contact_no] = @student.parent.contact_no+','+@student.name
end
```

But the hash is not getting created . I am not able to understand what is wrong in this  .

The code which works fine for a single student is not working in loop

```
@h=Hash["@student.parent.contact_no" = @student.parent.contact_no]
```

Comment: It looks like nothing is getting returned by your find. Also, if you are using Rails 3+ you should be using "where" and not "find"

Comment: Thanks for quick reply . find is working fine . The students object is being used by other part of the code without any problem . I am only getting error for the hash creation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is really a `@student` instance variable defined somewhere we can't see... it's most likely that you meant to not use the `@` sign in the loop. So this, instead:

```
@students.each do |student| 
  @h[student.parent.contact_no] = student.parent.contact_no+','+student.name
end
```

That said, there's lots you can do to clean this up and speed this up. I would do this, instead:

```
@students = Student.includes(:parents).where(<condition>)  # Eager load the associated parents
@h = @students.inject({}) do |acc, student|  # Initialize the new hash and loop
  acc[student.parent.contact_no] = "#{student.parent.contact_no},#{student.name}"  # String interpolation is faster than concatenation
  acc  # Return the accumulator
end
```

Here, `inject` (sometimes referred to as `reduce`) will take care of initializing the new hash and then returning the built-up hash at the end. Then, because we used eager loading of the `parents` association we won't be doing a database lookup on each iteration of the loop. Finally, string interpolation (`"#{}"`) is faster than string concatination (`"" + ""`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out and for the clean way of doing it and the tips .